# Preparing requested page Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, server-side-rendering, strapi

I'm using Gatsby as a front-end, and Strapi as my back-end to create my website. However, when I clicked my **blog**, it only shows white blank page, and when I checked it on my localhost, it shows these errors. Anyone have ever experienced this error?

[image]

[image]

Here is my Gatsby-node.js

```
const path = require("path")

// create pages dynamically
exports.createPages = async ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      blogs: allStrapiBlogs {
        nodes {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  const prodres = await graphql(`
    {
      products: allStrapiProduct {
        nodes {
          slug
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  result.data.blogs.nodes.forEach(blog => {
    createPage({
      path: `/blogs/${blog.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`src/templates/blog-template.js`),
      context: {
        slug: blog.slug,
      },
    })
  })

  prodres.data.products.nodes.forEach(product => {
    createPage({
      path: `/product/${product.slug}`,
      component: path.resolve(`src/templates/product-template.js`),
      context: {
        slug: product.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you post any of the relevant `gatsby-node.js` code? Also, take a look [this guide](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/content-api/integrations/gatsby.html#getting-started-with-gatsby) to check if you configured the settings correctly.

Comment: @Y.S. Hi, I've updated the question with my gatsby-node.js, I really appreciate you trying to help, thank you!

Comment: Do those queries work in the graphql ide?

Comment: @Y.S.Yap, they worked well

Comment: Can you provide your template for blog posts?

Comment: Nevermind, its all good! @FerranBuireu